# Select records from table where table name come from another table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We generate tables dynamically Eg. Table T_1, T_2, T_3, etc & we can get that table names from another table by following query.

`SELECT CONCAT('T_', T_ID) AS T_NAME FROM T_NAMES WHERE T_KEY = 'ABC';`

Now I want to get records from this retrieved table name. What can I do ?

I'm doing like following but that's not working :

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT('T_', T_ID) AS T_NAME FROM T_NAMES WHERE T_KEY = 'ABC')`

**FYI :** I'm hitting two individual queries as of now though I want to eliminate one **and** I can not follow cursor/procedure approach due to some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure which utilizes refcursor seems to be the most appropriate to me. Here's an example:

```
SQL> -- creating test case (your T_NAMES table and T_1 which looks like Scott's DEPT)
SQL> create table t_names (t_id number, t_key varchar2(3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t_names values (1, 'ABC');

1 row created.

SQL> create table t_1 as select * from dept;

Table created.

SQL> -- a procedure; accepts KEY and returns refcursor
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_key in varchar2, par_out out sys_refcursor)
  3  as
  4    l_t_name varchar2(30);
  5  begin
  6    select 'T_' || t_id
  7      into l_t_name
  8      from t_names
  9      where t_key = par_key;
 10
 11    open par_out for 'select * from ' || l_t_name;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

OK, let's test it:

```
SQL> var l_out refcursor
SQL> exec p_test('ABC', :l_out)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_out

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: Nicely explained but unfortunately I can not use either procedure or cursor approach.

Comment: We have limited access to DB and also why we use cursor/procedure if we can use simple SQLs ?

Comment: Aha. So, feel free to use your "simple SQL", if you can. I'd like to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

I could propose to you Dynamic SQL.
First of all, you need to create a cursor. The cursor will iterate by the dynamic tables. Then you could use dynamic SQL to create a query and then execute it.

So example:

1. https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_C81136WLRFYZF8ION6Q57GWE1.html - detailed cursor example.
2. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13057 - dynamic SQL in Oracle